# A proof for the regularity $k[x_1,x_2,...,x_n]$ based on Hilbert's syzygy theorem

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Wikipedia states that:

> In particular, if $k$ is a field, the polynomial ring $k[x_1,x_2,...,x_n]$ is regular. This is Hilbert's syzygy theorem.

I know that if $M$ be a maximal ideal of  $k[x_1,x_2,...,x_n]$ then $M$ can be generated by $n$ elements. Also, ht $M=n$ hence  $k[x_1,x_2,...,x_n]$ is regular ring.

But I really want to  know how one can prove the regularity of $k[x_1,x_2,...,x_n]$ by using Hilbert's syzygy.

For more clearance, I learn this form of Hilbert's syzygy theorem taken from the book **Steps in commutative algebra** by R.Y.Sharp.

> Let $(R,M)$ be a local regular ring of dimension $d$, and $G$ be a finitely generated $R$-module. Then there exists an exact sequence 
>   \begin{equation*}
> 0\to F_d\xrightarrow{f_d} F_{d-1}\to\cdots\to F_i\xrightarrow{f_i}\cdots\to F_1\xrightarrow{f_1} F_0\xrightarrow{f_0} G\to 0
> \end{equation*}
>   of $R$-modules and $R$-homomorphisms in which $F_0,F_1,...,F_d$ are all finitely generated free $R$-modules.